# Meaning of 身もフタもない

Tags: set-phrases, conjunctions

> 怒られるタイプの人のことを考えていて、自分が怒られたんじゃ、**身もフタもない**じゃないの
>   I've been thinking about people who are the type to get scolded and, I scold myself...

I can't make any sense out of the part in bold. Literally I get, "There's neither a container nor a lid, is there". I guess this is some sort of set phrase.

Also, what's going on with the conjuction at the second comma? I thought じゃ was just だ but I can't continue a sentence after だ can I?

**Edit:**
From the comments below I now have "...getting oneself scolded is blunt isn't it?". Afraid I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? 身もふた (蓋) もない is a basic idiom and I hope that it is explained in any decent dictionary. By the way, 自分が怒られる does not mean “I scold myself.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto  I've checked the ones I know that provide English translations. They had nothing. My Japanese is not good enough to look at the Japanese ones.

Comment: Try [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%82%E8%93%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%20)

Comment: @Blavius Thanks. I now know it means point blank/blunt, but the overall sentence is still meaningless to me.

Comment: Neither じゃ in this sentence is a dialectal form of だ (they're both contractions of では - Standard Japanese contractions).

Comment: @user3856370 I also feel difficulty in understanding this sentence. It's not an situation I, at least, would expect this idiom. Maybe more context before (or after)?

Comment: 「元も子もない」あたりならしっくりくるのですが・・　ありがちな誤用かという気がします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some definitions on the net:

> 身も蓋もない
>
> - 言葉が露骨すぎて、潤いも含みもない。
> - 露骨すぎて情緒もない。
> - 直接過ぎて、話の続けようがない。

So it refers to some very explicit/direct/honest expression which may sound harsh or uninteresting. Obviously it doesn't fit in the context you provided.

As pointed out in the comment, that person was probably confusing the phrase with 元も子もない, which means "[to try to gain something but end up in losing everything](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%83%E3%82%82%E5%AD%90%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)".

In this sentence, じゃ is a colloquialism for では.

> 怒られるタイプの人のことを考えていて、自分が怒られたんじゃ、**元も子もない**じゃないの。
>   Thinking about people who are the type to get scolded and ending up in being scolded is a total loss for you.

Comment: If I could rephrase your translation to make it seem more natural, I would say: "Thinking about the type of people who scold, when they are scolded themselves, isn't it a total loss?"